# Microsoft Graph API: admin can't list other users people

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Logged in as the Office 365 Global Administrator, I want to get the relevant people list for any user in Active Directory.

I can get my calls to return using

```
https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/users('my.address@contoso.com')/people
```

and

```
https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/users/{the user id}/people
```

and

```
https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/users('{the user id}')/people
```

and

```
https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/users/my.address@contoso.com/people
```

but, as an Office 365 admin with `People.Read.All` consent in the app, the call only returns one person (the target user's profile) for any user but myself. If I call it for my `user` I get a list of ten people

If I log in as that other person and make the People List API call it returns the expected ten results.

JWT scope: `"scp": "Files.ReadWrite Mail.Send People.Read.All User.Read`

I have to change the scope to `People.Read` for the non-admin.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_people

Comment: You can only fetch people who are in your contacts list.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  The API documentation does not mention anything like that. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_people

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood your question. I though you were trying to get contacts of some other users. Let me post my answer.

Comment: Additional notes: This is a work/school account and I made sure to explicitly add People.Read.All delegated permissions for the app in the Microsoft application registration portal.  I am using the Graph Quickstart Xamarin app with updated Microsoft.Graph 1.6.2 nuget package.  I get the same results in the Graph Explorer on the website.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I used the explorer and tried there demo account. It seems to work perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this issue. When you login as a normal user with `People.Read.All`, are they able to read other user's people? Trying to rule out if this is something specific to an Admin.

Comment: An admin permissions delegation is required to use People.Read.All.  You cannot log in as a regular user to try this.  The permissions delegation prevents login.

Comment: That isn't accurate. The `People.Read.All` scope requires `Admin Consent` before a normal user can authorize that scope. It is not limited to Admins only.  When you execute `Admin Consent` you are authorizing the App so Users of that tenant can use the application. "Admin Consent" is different than "User is Admin".

Comment: People.Read.All is an admin only permissions delegation.  To me, this meant that only an admin could use it.  This was confirmed to me when I tried to log in as a non-admin user and was presented with a message telling me that using the application required an admin account to read the information.  When I removed the People.Read.All delegation it let the non-admin user log in and use the application.  Attempts to access other users people list in that scenario resulted in Access Denied.

Answer (score 0):

> the call only returns one person (the target user's profile) for any
>   user but myself.

Answer is in the API Doc. As the document says.

> Retrieve a collection of person objects ordered by their relevance to
>   the user, which is determined by the user's communication and
>   collaboration patterns and business relationships.

The following request gets the people most relevant to another person in the signed-in user's organization

> https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/users('my.address@contoso.com')/people

It might happen that there is no one relevant to that user.

If you want the list of contacts in other user's contact list then you can refer to this one :
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_contacts

**UPDATE**

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

I used the demo account on this website. I used this query
**https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/08fa38e4-cbfa-4488-94ed-c834da6539df/people** It worked.

This query gives the same result

**https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('08fa38e4-cbfa-4488-94ed-c834da6539df')/people**

Same result
**https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('MiriamG@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com')/people/**

Same result
**https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/MiriamG@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com/people/**

**If you still can't get it to work and specially on Graph Explorer Website. Then it means that according to Microsoft there are no relevant people for that particular user.**

As you can see there are different ways to use the same thing. Try it all if it works. Let me know.

Comment: I'm not trying to get their contacts.  I want to see the list of scored, relevant users as returned from the people API call.  This person does have relevant people.  It is a well-used account going back many years.  When I log in as that user I get the expected result when calling me/people or /users/id/people.  The expected result is a list of relevant people with scores.

Comment: Could u try using user principal name in place of id

Comment: My original post stated that I had...and I am.  The first REST call in my post illustrates that.

Comment: I know but I mean like this. 
https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/users/{the user principal}/people.  And https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/users('id')/people I have used graph   api in past and I know it's a pain.. I used the graph client on dot net.

Comment: tried all variations of the API again and it still just returns one result for the user.  I am logging in as myself (Office 365 admin with all nessesary delegated permissions) and trying to list relevant people for my wife's account.  All it returns is her account.  When I log in as her the people list returns a full list.  I'm really looking for someone from Microsoft to weigh in...they pointed us to SO for these kinds of issues.  The API is not working as expected when following the docs.  I have tried adding other permissions as well but nothing has worked.

Comment: If you downvote an answer, Please also leave a comment why you downvoted it.

Comment: @SeanAnderson I don't know why it is happening. You need to check your token scope as said by Dmitry . But still then your accounts should have worked with Graph Explorer

Comment: Token: "scp": "Files.ReadWrite Mail.Send People.Read.All User.Read",  Because this was happening with the graph explorer I did not expect the token...but there it is.

Comment: I know u did not down vote it. I was just saying it. Your scope permissions looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing this behavior in the [Graph Explorer sample tenant](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). The behavior seems to indicate that this is auth-related. I would try to sign in with the admin again and make sure that you've consented to any of the admin-only scopes. Additionally, one thing you can do to figure out whether you have the appropriate scope in your token is [decoding the JWT](http://jwt.calebb.net/) and examining the "scp" collection.

Comment: "scp": "Files.ReadWrite Mail.Send People.Read.All User.Read

Comment: Good to see that the People.Read.All scope is there. Do you see this behavior if you don't specify the port (`graph.microsoft.com/v1.0` vs. `graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0`)?

Comment: Removed the port from the URL...same behavior.